# link a dataset to a rdlc file

Tags: c#, dataset, report, rdlc

I created a report with a rdlc.
when I add a dataset to this file and I want to use this dataset in expression window, and when I select "fields" item in the "Category" box, Display a message in the third box that says: "Report item not linked to a dataset."
What I can do to link this dataset to my report.

Comment: how did you add the dataset to the file? can you show the report definition text file?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to user the 'Report Wizard' option which will setup everything correctly.
Then you have a choice of layout your report as you want because the wizard will force you to choose a layout, which you may not like :(
Of course I am assuming you are using Visual Studio.